# Oracle SQL - matching different rows by multiple fields

Tags: sql, oracle, matching

I am trying to solve the matching of different customers, from different entities. Using **only SQL** select and "with" syntax, **no PL/SQL**. Below is a simple example. There are three customers, who are each 3 different individuals, but are recorded slightly different in different entities (1,2,3). I am matching them by P1, P2 and P3 field. In addition, P2 and P3 needs to have a cross-field check.

Customer **David** - only in entity 1 and 2, in both entities has P1 = 100. Easy match. Gets 'G1'

Customer **Lloyd** - only in entity 1 and 3, matches with cross-field check of P2 = P3. Gets 'G2'

Customer **Mark** - in all three entities. In entity 1 and 3 they match by P1. But the row in entity 2 matches only with cross-field check with entity 1, P2. This person needs to have 'G3' assigned in all three entities. Thoughest case.

The G, eg. G3243 represents customer's unique group ID. It is the same for one customer inside different entities and different from all other customers' Group IDs.

Any ideas how to do this? Sample table below:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Nmf.png)

sample data:

```
with 
sample as (
select 1 as entity, 'DAVID' as customer, 100 as P1, 'hjk' as P2, null as P3 from dual
union all
select 2 as entity, 'DAVID' as customer, 100 as P1, 'heeee' as P2, null as P3 from dual
union all
select 1 as entity, 'Lloyd' as customer, null as P1, 'dfe' as P2, null as P3 from dual
union all
select 1 as entity, 'LLOYD' as customer, null as P1, null as P2, 'dfe' as P3 from dual
union all
select 1 as entity, 'MARK' as customer, 300 as P1, 'abc' as P2, null as P3 from dual
union all
select 2 as entity, 'MARC' as customer, 0 as P1, null as P2, 'abc' as P3 from dual
union all
select 3 as entity, 'Mark' as customer, 300 as P1, 'texttt' as P2, null as P3 from dual

)
select *  from sample;
```

Comment: What have you tried, what is not working?  Not specific answer but you can do self join (join to same table with alias) and in joins you can do JOIN on x=y AND y=z  OR  and use parenthesis to group AND with OR combinations.

Comment: First I went into this direction of doing a group by of each P and joining them back to the same table for those, who have count() more than 1. All well for most cases, but not for "MARC". This 'G3' needs to be Mark's Group ID, has to be the same for all three rows and different from all other persons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right the expected outcome should say how many correlations are present in the data for each customer. Column P1 is considered on its own and columns P2 and P3 define possible additional ties if they are cross related. Here is one possible solution using your initial sample data.

I try to count relations on columns P1, P2 and P3 by creating cte ("sample_counts")

```sql
    sample_counts AS
        (
            Select
                s1.ENTITY "ENTITY",
                UPPER(s1.CUSTOMER) "CUSTOMER",
                Max(CASE WHEN s1.P1 Is Not Null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "CNT_P1",
                Max((Select Count(*) From sample Where P2 = s1.P3 )) "CNT_P2_P3",
                Max((Select Count(*) From sample Where P3 = s1.P2 )) "CNT_P3_P2",
                Max(Nvl((Select UPPER(CUSTOMER) From sample Where P2 = s1.P3 ), UPPER(s1.CUSTOMER))) "CUSTOMER_2"
            From
                sample s1
            Group By
                UPPER(s1.CUSTOMER), s1.ENTITY
            Order By 
                UPPER(s1.CUSTOMER), s1.ENTITY
        )
/*
    "sample_counts" (cte) resulting dataset

        ENTITY CUSTOMER     CNT_P1  CNT_P2_P3  CNT_P3_P2 CUSTOMER_2
    ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
             1 DAVID             1          0          0 DAVID      
             2 DAVID             1          0          0 DAVID      
             1 LLOYD             0          1          1 LLOYD      
             2 MARC              1          1          0 MARK       
             1 MARK              1          0          1 MARK       
             3 MARK              1          0          0 MARK       
*/
```

The resulting dataset gives us counts of relations (as 1 or 0) over different columns for each customer and did some naming unification in column CUSTOMER_2. Even from this dataset it is obvious that David has just one level of correlations (CNT_P1), that Lloyd has two levels by cross joinning CNT_P2 and CNT_P3 (none on CNT_P1), and finally that Mark  (or Marc) has correlation on all three columns. As dataset is grouped by, in the main SQL we should join it to your sample data in order to get all rows but now with **Gx** representing the group correlations as G1, G2, G3.

Here is the final SQL with the result:

```sql
SELECT
    sc.ENTITY "ENTITY",
    sc.CUSTOMER_2 "CUSTOMER",
    s.P1 "P1",
    s.P2 "P2",
    s.P3 "P3",
    'G' || To_Char(
                    Max(CNT_P1) OVER (PARTITION BY sc.CUSTOMER_2 ORDER BY sc.CUSTOMER_2) +
                    Max(CNT_P2_P3) OVER (PARTITION BY sc.CUSTOMER_2 ORDER BY sc.CUSTOMER_2) + 
                    Max(CNT_P3_P2) OVER (PARTITION BY sc.CUSTOMER_2 ORDER BY sc.CUSTOMER_2) 
                  ) "GRP"
FROM
    sample_counts sc
INNER JOIN 
    sample s ON(s.ENTITY = sc.ENTITY And UPPER(s.CUSTOMER) = sc.CUSTOMER)
ORDER BY 
    CUSTOMER_2, ENTITY
--  
--  R e s u l t :
--  
--      ENTITY CUSTOMER         P1 P2     P3  GRP                                     
--  ---------- -------- ---------- ------ --- --------
--           1 DAVID           100 hjk        G1      
--           2 DAVID           100 heeee      G1      
--           1 LLOYD               dfe        G2      
--           1 LLOYD                      dfe G2      
--           1 MARK            300 abc        G3      
--           2 MARK              0        abc G3      
--           3 MARK            300 texttt     G3
```

If you want to have the original customer name from your data then just select s.CUSTOMER here (instead of sc.CUSTOMER_2).
Try it with your actual data. I realy do hope this would be usefull. Regards...

**A D D I T I O N**

Please try this code on your data. I added a few more rows (John and Anne) in the sample data and changed the code according to the comments. Hope it could help you now:

```sql
with 
    sample as 
        (
            select 1 as entity, 'DAVID' as customer, 100 as P1, 'hjk' as P2, null as P3 from dual   union all
            select 2 as entity, 'DAVID' as customer, 100 as P1, 'heeee' as P2, null as P3 from dual union all
            select 1 as entity, 'JOHN' as customer, 200 as P1, 'hjklm' as P2, null as P3 from dual  union all
            select 2 as entity, 'JOHN' as customer, 200 as P1, 'xdxxdxd' as P2, null as P3 from dual union all
            select 1 as entity, 'Lloyd' as customer, null as P1, 'dfe' as P2, null as P3 from dual  union all
            select 1 as entity, 'LLOYD' as customer, null as P1, null as P2, 'dfe' as P3 from dual  union all
            select 1 as entity, 'ANNE' as customer, null as P1, Null as P2, 'xls' as P3 from dual   union all
            select 2 as entity, 'ANNE' as customer, null as P1, 'xls' as P2, Null as P3 from dual   union all
            select 1 as entity, 'MARK' as customer, 300 as P1, 'abc' as P2, null as P3 from dual    union all
            select 2 as entity, 'MARC' as customer, 0 as P1, null as P2, 'abc' as P3 from dual      union all
            select 3 as entity, 'Mark' as customer, 300 as P1, 'texttt' as P2, null as P3 from dual
        ),
    sample_counts AS
        (
            Select
                ROWNUM "RN", s1.ENTITY "ENTITY", UPPER(s1.CUSTOMER) "CUSTOMER", CASE WHEN s1.P1 Is Not Null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END "CNT_P1",
                Nvl(To_Char(s1.P1), '0') "P1", (Select Count(*) From sample Where P2 = s1.P3 ) "CNT_P2_P3", Nvl(To_Char(s1.P2), '0') "P2",
                (Select Count(*) From sample Where P3 = s1.P2 ) "CNT_P3_P2", Nvl(To_Char(s1.P3), '0') "P3",
                Nvl((Select UPPER(CUSTOMER) From sample Where P2 = s1.P3 ), UPPER(s1.CUSTOMER)) "CUSTOMER_2"
            From  sample s1
            Order By RN
        ),
    p_data AS
        (
            Select RN, CUSTOMER_2, 'P1' "COL", To_Char(P1) "PX", To_Char(CNT_P1) "CNT_X" From sample_counts Union All
            Select RN, CUSTOMER_2, 'P2' "COL", To_Char(P2) "PX", To_Char(CNT_P2_P3) "CNT_X" From sample_counts Union All
            Select RN, CUSTOMER_2, 'P3' "COL", To_Char(P3) "PX", To_Char(CNT_P3_P2) "CNT_X" From sample_counts 
            Order By RN, COL
        ),
    matches AS
        (
            SELECT  p.RN, p.CUSTOMER_2, p.COL, p.PX, p.CNT_X, sc.P1, sc.P2, sc.P3
            FROM    p_data p
            INNER JOIN  sample_counts sc ON(sc.RN = p.RN)
            WHERE   p.CNT_X <> '0'
            ORDER BY p.RN
        )
SELECT DISTINCT
    sc.ENTITY, sc.CUSTOMER_2, sc.P1 "P1", sc.P2 "P2", sc.P3 "P3", 
    'G' || To_Char(Min(m.RN) OVER(PARTITION BY sc.CUSTOMER_2 ORDER BY sc.CUSTOMER_2)) "GRP"
FROM
    sample_counts sc
INNER JOIN
    matches m ON (m.RN = sc.RN)
ORDER BY 
    sc.CUSTOMER_2, sc.ENTITY
--  
--  R e s u l t :
-- 
--      ENTITY CUSTOMER_2 P1                                       P2      P3  GRP                                     
--  ---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------- ------- --- -----------------------------------------
--           1 ANNE       0                                        0       xls G7                                        
--           2 ANNE       0                                        xls     0   G7                                        
--           1 DAVID      100                                      hjk     0   G1                                        
--           2 DAVID      100                                      heeee   0   G1                                        
--           1 JOHN       200                                      hjklm   0   G3                                        
--           2 JOHN       200                                      xdxxdxd 0   G3                                        
--           1 LLOYD      0                                        0       dfe G5                                        
--           1 LLOYD      0                                        dfe     0   G5                                        
--           1 MARK       300                                      abc     0   G9                                        
--           2 MARK       0                                        0       abc G9                                        
--           3 MARK       300                                      texttt  0   G9
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I dont think this will do just yet. If I add one more person, for example which also has 2 rows and matches by P1, it will have the same G1 assigned as David. Which is not OK. 

If i try to put a more concrete example – P1 would be a national ID number, P2 is Tax/VAT number, and P3 is Foreign Tax/VAT number. This specific case is for a »consolidated customer registry« for multiple company branches.

Comment: Most customers will match by P1 or by P2, because we have their national ID and Tax numbers populated. Some entities are in different countries, therefore crosscheck for tax and foreign tax number. 
The 'G', eg G4289 would mean that rows with G4289 represent one specific person that can occcur in different entities. If I as a person occur in different entities, I need to have the G4289 in every one of them and no other person must have that G.

Comment: OK, I got it wrong, obviously. Could you explain how did you get G4289 and what is the logic behind it. Additionaly, it would be easyer to answer if there is more data provided. It is a bit clearer now but not all of it. As I understand - every person should end up with his own (unique) G number. I still don't get it how that G number is defined. To be exact why G4289 and not G333?

Comment: The value of G is not relevant, its only purpose is for grouping of the customers in later stages. Currently I would get it by rownum in my attempts.

Comment: @atoman I have just posted the Addition with the changes from comments. Please try it... Regards....